# What's the difference between "established" and "founded"

Tags: meaning, differences

In this sentence:
"CARE was ...... in 1945 to help people after World War II."

A. founded 
B. built
C. established
D. constructed

The answer is C. But why don't we use "founded" in this case, I think they have the same meaning. Can you help me to give a reason for that?

Comment: I agree that the meaning does seem the same, in this context.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CARE_(relief_agency)) uses "Founded in 1945". Both have same meaning and purpose here

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+founded+to%2Cwas+established+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20founded%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20established%20to%3B%2Cc0) indicates *was established to* is more prevalent than *was founded to*. It might be argued that *founded* inclines slightly more towards the (corporate) structure and *established* slightly more towards the principles, but it's a fine line.

Comment: 1. They do **not** have the exact same meaning. 2. Note the purpose clause at the end of the sentence. We do not use *founded* with a focus on purpose. "CARE was founded in 1945 (by .../ )"; "CARE was established in 1945 (for .../ to .../ with the aim of .../ )". HTH.

Comment: They are essentially equivalent.  One or the other may be used based on the impression one wants to give -- *founded* suggests an organization that originated with an individual (identified) person, while *established* suggests a more anonymous origin, where the founders are not considered significant to the organization's purposes or history.  But this is not writ in stone.

Comment: Don't forget the Founding Fathers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular context, *founded* and *established* mean exactly the same thing.

**Found** — [MWLD](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/found)

> *verb* 1. to begin or create (something that is meant to last for a long time) : establish
>   *"The college was founded in 1793"*

**Establish** — [MWLD](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/establish)

> *verb* 2.a. to begin or create (something that is meant to last for a long time)
>   *"The city was established [=founded] in the 18th century."*

Wikipedia page for [CARE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CARE_(relief_agency)) uses *founded*:

> "..Founded in 1945, CARE is nonsectarian, impartial, and non-governmental.."

Here's an Ngram: ["was established in" vs "was founded in"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20founded%20in%2Cwas%20established%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20founded%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20established%20in%3B%2Cc0)

[image: Ngram]

Answer (score 0):

They are more or less the same. Interestingly, several definitions I found (such as this one: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/founded) used 'establish' in giving the definition of founded, despite listing it as a synonym. Seems rather foolish, I agree, and you'd be right to contest your test answer! :)

Comment: In the Oxford dictionary, I can find that the synonym of found is establish ^.^